# Trigger @Scheduled manually SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring

I have a `@Scheduled` annotated method in my class and I want to know if there is a way to trigger the method manually. Normally the method starts when I create an instance of my class and the only method I found to trigger it manually is to set a `boolean` flag like this:

```
private AtomicBoolean isEnabled = new AtomicBoolean(false);

@Override
public void startFlight() {
    isEnabled.set(true);
}

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
public void updateDroneLocation() {
    if (isEnabled.get()) {
        clientChannel.receiveData();
    }
}
```

So the `updateDroneLocation()` is ***"working"*** (please note the text font) only if I call the `startFlight()` first.

**But** is there any other method instead of using a `boolean` ?

Comment: Can't you just add an endpoint that calls the method?

Comment: As I've said, when you create an instance of the class which contains the method it would be like calling the `start()` method on a thread and the `@Scheduled` method is the `run()` method.

Comment: You can expose `startFlight()` method as REST endpoint.